# Tiles not updating completely in rendering in libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, rendering, game-physics

This is the code I am trying to make work correctly. When my character collides with a specific object this is supposed to run. The tiles gain the new properties, but do not change  in the rendering process.  my goal is  to give them the new properties and rendering the new tile.

```
collisionLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0);
                for(int x = 0; x < collisionLayer.getWidth();x++){
                    for(int y = 0; y < collisionLayer.getHeight();y++){
                        cell = collisionLayer.getCell(x,y);
  if(cell.getTile().getProperties().containsKey("hiddenwall")) {    
                        cell.setTile(map.getTileSets().getTile(2));
                    }
                    }
               }
```

this is the old code that worked. upon collision it would get the tile from the players location, and upon collision with a collision tile it will get the tile to the new block type and set it. The code below works and displays correctly. The code above does not. Anyone have an idea as to why?

```
Cell cell = collisionLayer.getCell(
                    (int) ((getX()) / (collisionLayer.getTileWidth() )),
                    (int) ((getY())/ (collisionLayer.getTileHeight() )));
             cell.setTile(map.getTileSets().getTile(2));
```

Comment: You say it is "supposed" to run. So does code in that statement ever runs?

Comment: yes the code does run. The 1st set of code is the code I am running now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was running my method in the wrong place. I needed to run it in the render method of my program. Though it did work in other places. (which was in my collision detection) with one tile at a tile. checking every tile on the map wasn't working with all of the other mechanics. Once I ran the code in the render method it worked like a charm every time.